# Solve BesselJ (J0) function in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to solve BesselJ function in R.
I know There are an infinite possibility but let's say I want to know the 100 or even the 1000 first values… is it possible?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: With uniroot I can only find one value at a time…
`J0 <- function(x){
  besselJ(nu = 0, x )
}

uniroot(J0, interval = c(0,3))` and I get 2.404847 which is the first value.

Comment: And when I try a larger interval, for example: `interval = c(0,10)`, It gives me the last value 8.653756 when I should get 2.404847, 5.52008 and 8.653728....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a visual thinker, so here's how I would approach this. First of all, set up a sequence of x values between, say, 1 and 100. Then get the value of BesselJ with n = 0 at each point:

```r
x <- seq(1, 100, 0.1)
y <- besselJ(x, 0)
```

Now put them in a data frame and plot them:

```
df <- data.frame(x, y)

library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()

p
```

[image]

Now we can see that wherever the roots are, there will be a change in sign of the y value, so let's identify the x values where the y values change sign. We can use these as points around which to look. We know, since our sequence is 0.1 apart, each root must fall between -0.1 and +0.1 of these points:

```r
lower <- x[which(diff(sign(y)) != 0)] - 0.1
```

So we can use these ranges as inputs to `uniroot`, provided we use `sapply` to feed the ranges into `uniroot` one-by-one.

```
bes <- function(x) besselJ(x, 0)
roots <- sapply(lower, function(z) uniroot(bes, interval = c(0, 0.2) + z)$root)
```

We now have our roots between 1 and 100:

```
roots
#>  [1]  2.404822  5.520077  8.653728 11.791554 14.930917 18.071084 21.211636 24.352494
#>  [9] 27.493463 30.634588 33.775837 36.917098 40.058441 43.199791 46.341164 49.482615
#> [17] 52.624066 55.765511 58.906984 62.048469 65.189983 68.331441 71.472982 74.614519
#> [25] 77.756026 80.897543 84.039092 87.180630 90.322155 93.463719 96.605241 99.746820
```

And we can show these are correct by adding them to our plot:

```r
p + geom_point(data = data.frame(x = roots, y = besselJ(roots, 0)),
               colour = "red")
```

[image]

In terms of speed, this will get you the first 1000 roots in under a 10th of a second:

```
bes1000 <- function()
{
  x <- seq(1, 3143, 0.1)
  y <- besselJ(x, 0)
  lower <- x[which(diff(sign(y)) != 0)] - 0.1
  bes <- function(x) besselJ(x, 0)
  roots <- sapply(lower, function(z) uniroot(bes, interval = c(0, 0.2) + z)$root)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(bes1000())
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  bes1000() 78.1617 81.22905 88.62894 83.09845 90.67025 396.5271   100
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer… this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A very brute-force (yet functional) approach would be to obtain the roots by minimization:

```
# tightly spaced grid
init_g <- seq(0,100,by = 1)

# objective function: sum of squares of the values of the Bessel function
J0 <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y) besselJ(nu = 0, y))
objective <- function(x) {sum(J0(x)^2)}

# minimize the objective functional with respect to the initial guess
# round the values to eliminate numerical uncertainty and output unique values
bessel_roots <- unique(round(nlm(objective, p=init_g, ndigit=4)$estimate, 4))
```

**Output**

```
> bessel_roots
 [1]  2.4048  5.5201  8.6537 11.7915 14.9309 18.0710 18.0711 21.2116 24.3525
[10] 27.4935 30.6346 33.7758 36.9171 40.0584 43.1997 43.1998 46.3412 49.4826
[19] 52.6240 55.7655 58.9070 62.0484 65.1899 68.3314 71.4730 71.4729 74.6145
[28] 77.7560 80.8975 84.0391 84.0390 87.1806 90.3221 93.4637 96.6052 99.7468
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's in fact slow but it works !

Comment: @AuronusBen better approach would be to find roots one by one and use the previous solution as an initial guess to the next solution. But the approach above is the fastest to code.

Comment: @AuronusBen You can use these values as an initial guess by further refinement using `uniroot`. The approach is slow because it is brute-force, but it is the fastest to program as I mentioned